# Where is the ********?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

I wanted to figure out the ******** of my five friends I recently met online but they didn't want to say it straight forward, so they said it in a cryptic way.

I asked them one by one and these are the answers I was given.

Person 1: Mr yes → (5)

Person 2: You speak → (3)

Person 3: Yes dude → (5)

Person 4: Number road → (6)

Person 5: You going to → (6)

---

**Can you figure out how to interpret these answers?**

Comment: Watch your language, Mr. @Prim3numbah!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the asterisks here are hiding the word:

> **LOCATION** (or equally, HOMELAND or something similar) - specifically, each friend is concealing the name of their **country** in some cryptic-esque wordplay...

Person 1: Mr yes → (5)

> **KENYA** = KEN (a man's name) + YA (yes)
>
>  or (possibly better in keeping with the 'soundalike' style of the others)
>
>  **SYRIA** = sounds a bit like "Sir yeah" (in particular accents)

Person 2: You speak → (3)

> **USA** = sounds like "You say"

Person 3: Yes dude → (5)

> **YEMEN** = sounds like "Yeah man"

Person 4: Number road → (6)

> **NORWAY** = sounds a bit like what you get when you put together NO. (number) + WAY (road)

Person 5: You going to → (6)

> **UGANDA** = sounds like "You go'n' to"